# Как удалить элемент из списка если в нем есть кусок определенной фразы

Tags: python-3.x

с помощью `post` запроса я получил список

```
list = ['\n\n\n', ‘A6466/22 - RWY 07/25 CLSD FOR\n’, '\n\n\n', 'L9603/22 - AIRSPACE CLSD AS FLW:\n1. AREA: 582300N0763400E', '\n\n\n', 'L9342/22 - AIRSPACE CLSD AS FLW:\n1. AREA: 537189N0982510E']
```

список достаточно большой, но мне не нужны элементы в которых внутри есть фраза `AIRSPACE CLSD AS FLW:` это только часть элемента.

Как удалить из списка данные элементы?

пробовал вот так:

```
for x in list[::-1]:
    if 'AIRSPACE' in list[::-1]:
        list.remove(x)
```

и вот так:

```
if 'AIRSPACE' in list:
    del list[list.index('AIRSPACE')]
```

А как надо было?)

Comment: обычно это делают с помощью спискового включения или `filter()`

Comment: по типу - delta = [x for x in list if x=='AIRSPACE'] ? возвращает пустой список print(delta) -> []

Comment: спасибо, помогли! А как теперь эти отфильтрованные элементы удалить из списка?

Comment: Точнее `if 'AIRSPACE' not in x`. Тогда в delta соберутся все элементы без космоса

Comment: Огромнейшая благодарность!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Огромная благодарность Алексей Р, выручил!

```
delta = [x for x in list if 'AIRSPACE' not in x]
```

Comment: Переменную лучше не называть list, чтобы не затенять стандартную функцию